# How can I ensure testNG reports exceptions for the correct test?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, testng

I'm attempting to create a suite of tests to run in parallel using testNG, PerfectoMobile, and Maven. The tests are running in parallel, but it seems like exceptions are being reported for a random thread each time. I know this because the test i have named "Xperia M2" is the one that is generating the exception, but testNG's IntelliJ reporter shows the exception coming from (seemingly) random tests instead.

You can see a screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbGkG.png

As you can see from the screenshot, the test "Test Android HTC One M9" is reporting the exception that was generated from the Xperia M2 test (just below it, marked as skipped (as a side-note, why is that test being marked as skipped?)).

Here is my TestNG code:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">
    <parameter name="mcm" value="-redacted-" />
    <parameter name="mcmUser" value="-redacted-" />
    <parameter name="mcmPassword" value="-redacted-" />
    <test name="Test Android Galaxy S6">
        <parameter name="platformName" value="Android" />
        <parameter name="app" value="-redacted-" />
        <parameter name="appId" value="-redacted-" />
        <parameter name="deviceModel" value="Galaxy S6" />
        <classes>
            <class name="testNG.SmokeTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test Android LG G4">
        <parameter name="platformName" value="Android" />
        <parameter name="app" value="-redacted-" />
        <parameter name="appId" value="-redacted-" />
        <parameter name="deviceModel" value="G4" />
        <classes>
            <class name="testNG.SmokeTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test Android HTC One M9">
        <parameter name="platformName" value="Android" />
        <parameter name="app" value="-redacted-" />
        <parameter name="appId" value="-redacted-" />
        <parameter name="deviceModel" value="One M9" />
        <classes>
            <class name="testNG.SmokeTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test Android Galaxy Note 4">
        <parameter name="platformName" value="Android" />
        <parameter name="app" value="-redacted-" />
        <parameter name="appId" value="-redacted-" />
        <parameter name="deviceModel" value="Galaxy Note 4" />
        <classes>
            <class name="testNG.SmokeTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test Android Xperia M2">
        <parameter name="platformName" value="Android" />
        <parameter name="app" value="-redacted-" />
        <parameter name="appId" value="-redacted-" />
        <parameter name="deviceModel" value="Xperia M2" />
        <classes>
            <class name="testNG.SmokeTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test Android Xperia Z3">
        <parameter name="platformName" value="Android" />
        <parameter name="app" value="-redacted-" />
        <parameter name="appId" value="-redacted-" />
        <parameter name="deviceModel" value="Xperia Z3" />
        <classes>
            <class name="testNG.SmokeTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I've tried my best to search around for this question, but i can't seem to figure out exactly how to phrase it. I was hoping someone here could help me out!

Comment: P.S.: I'm using a ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> to generate webdrivers for the threads in (what i hope is) a thread-safe manner, still getting the above behavior.

Comment: P.P.S.: Maybe this is because the exception is being generated in the setup method (@BeforeClass)?

Comment: Yes, if TestNG setup method fails the test is skipped, which should make sense. But why it affects completely different test (even being executed in parallel) is a mystery for me. May TestNG be confused by the same `@BeforeClass` being executed multiple times for each test in XML? Could you please move setup to `@BeforeTest` method and see if it changes anything?